# Aggregating/ separating dummies

Tags: regression, categorical-encoding

Let's say that I want to add a control which is a dummy for the weekend in my regression. I assume that Saturday and Sunday behave the same in my model.

Would it make any difference if I have one dummy for the weekend, rather than having two separate dummies, one for Saturday and one for Sunday?

Comment: What you're calling an assumption is really a hypothesis. If you fit separate dummy (indicator) variables for Saturday and Sunday you can then test whether the coefficients are the same. If they are, you only need one. If that coefficient is not significant you may not need either. (The wording in this comment is loose, but I hope the flavour is evident.)

Comment: @NickCox You can also just keep it as an assumption, if you have good reason to. Model building based on p-values is controversial. But I agree that you need to make op your mind if you assume it a priori to be true (there is no difference) or want to test a posteriori if it is true, which is not clear from the question.

Comment: @Knarpie Indeed. It's not my choice; it's the OP's to make. He can assume it. He can check  whether it's true.  If you can't change your model in the light of results, what is science about? It seems to be dogma in some fields that all hypotheses must be set down before the analysis, and I do take points about fishing for significance,  but where do hypotheses come from? Looking at previous results, for one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! Indeed I could test it, however my question is on a simplified problem. In real life problems you may want to make dummies out of factor variables in order to use them in the regression, and because of the big number of variables it may be tiresome to try all of them. I was hoping for more statistical answer. Maybe, when I have time I will use a simulated data set to test it.